# Unable to install Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015

[As you can see from this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpjty.png)
this is the error I get any time I try and install VS2015 fro either the web downloader or the .ISO.

I've done some background research and it seems that some how a windows update might be an issue? I don't know if I'm missing updates or that the update is being blocked some how.

[Here are the logs of the install.](http://pasted.co/281dfa6c)

Comment: Did you check the install log file for any clues?

Comment: Oh duh, forgot to post them. I'm not sure what I would even be looking for to be honest.

Comment: Install this it is an important update https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226 without it VS probably wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that but it immediately fails see pic http://puu.sh/lnxN3/2ac5da8417.png

Comment: Finally got the update to work by disabling and reinstalling windows update! Thanks!